# Lightning:overLayLibrary issue Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'la' of undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

trying to implement the Modal using 
Lightning:overLayLibrary as per this link [lightningOverlayLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:overlayLibrary/documentation) i am facing the below issue

> ```
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'la' of undefined
>     at Object.dispatchGlobalEvent (aura_prod.js:757)
>     at a (lightning-overlay-utils.js:2)
>     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
>     at Promise.all.then.a
> ```

**Component**

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:button label="New REcord" name="modal"  onclick="{!c.handleShowModal}"></lightning:button>
</aura:component>
```

**controller.js**

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

},
   handleShowModal: function(component, evt, helper) {
    var matterid = component.get("v.recordId");
    var modalBody;
    $A.createComponent("c:demoPagecomponent", {},
       function(content, status) {
           if (status === "SUCCESS") {
               modalBody = content;
               alert(modalBody);
               component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({
                header: "Application Confirmation",
                   body: modalBody, 
                   showCloseButton: true,
                   cssClass: "mymodal",
                   closeCallback: function() {
                       alert('You closed the alert!');
                   }
               })
           }                               
       });
    }
})
```

**demoPagecomponent**

```
<aura:component>
<div>
Hello
</div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Would you mind adding your code? We can replicate that in our org and see whats wrong. Thanks

Comment: updated please look into it . i think this line causing problem
               component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({

Comment: Where you are getting this error?
In lightning App? or Lightning Experience ?

Comment: it is in Lightning App

Comment: You are using `component.find('overlayLib')` but I cannot find this attribute in your markup...

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question while finding the solution for the same and after a few hard luck, I found that I was trying to preview it using a **Lightning:app** and that's what throwing this error. If you try to access somewhere in a record page or quick action then it will work without throwing this error.

> lightning:overlayLibrary will not work in the lightning:app.

I hope this tip will help someone for sure.

Answer (score 1):

In order to Create a popup inside **Lightning:app** , you need to create a custom popup , Please follow this link and put into the modal body the component tag you want to display , I tried this and it worked ! .

http://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/04/15/modal-box-lightning-component-salesforce/